# Regex to find string arguments of a function call (lookbehind with multiple hits)

Tags: regex, grep, regex-group, pcre, regex-greedy

I want to use grep (PCRE) to find all single-quoted strings that are passed to my function `foo()`.

Example functions calls in my source code and the expected hits:

```js
foo('Alice')                    -> Expected Hits: Alice
foo('Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie')  -> Expected Hits: Alice, Bob, Charlie
foo(flag ? 'Alice' : 'Bob')     -> Expected Hits: Alice, Bob
```

My regex:

```
foo\([^\)]*\K(?:')([^'\)]*)(?:'\))
```

However, I get only the last single-quoted string for each function call and not all as you can see in my regex101 playground: https://regex101.com/r/FlzDYp/1

How can I define a PCRE conform regex for grep to get all expected hits?

Comment: This may be difficult to handle using `grep` by itself.  Would Python or PHP be available to you?

Comment: PHP isn't an option for me. However, I can use bash and all other standard Linux tools.

Comment: What about Python?

Comment: I would prefer standard bash. However Javascript with node would be reasonable alternative for me.

Comment: Depending on what is allowed between the single quotes: `grep -oP "(?:\bfoo\((?=[^()]*\))|\G(?!^))[^']*(?:'\h*[,:]\h*)?'\K\w+" file` See https://regex101.com/r/K7jXR3/1

Comment: Only ASCII letters and underscores are allowed between the single quotes. I don't completely understand your regex yet. However, the result looks exactly for what I'm looking for!

Comment: Martin, two explanations may help: `\K` discards all previously-matched characters from the match that is returned and `\G` causes the search to begin at the end of the previous match (or at the start of the string if there has been no previous match).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use grep with `-P` for PCRE and `-o` to print only the matched parts.

The pattern in parts matches:

- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\bfoo\(` Match the word `foo` followed by `(`
  - `(?=[^()]*\))` Positive lookahead to assert a closing `)` to the right
  - `|` Or
  - `\G(?!^)` Assert the current position at the end of the previous match, but not at the start of the string (as `\G` can match at those 2 positions)
- `)` Close the non capture group
- `[^']*` match optional chars other than `'`
- `(?:'\h*[,:]\h*)?` Optionally match either `,` or `:` between optional spaces
- `'` Match the `'`
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far as we don't want that `'` in the result
- `\w+` Match 1 or more word characters

Example:

```
grep -oP "(?:\bfoo\((?=[^()]*\))|\G(?!^))[^']*(?:'\h*[,:]\h*)?'\K\w+" file
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K7jXR3/1) for the matches.

---

An alternative using `awk` first matching the format `foo(....)` and then printing all the values between the single quotes that are alphanumeric or an underscore using a while loop.

The `\047` is a single quote here.

```
awk '/foo\([^][]*\)/ {
  while(match($0, /\047[[:alnum:]_]+\047/)) {
    print substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-2)
    $0 = substr($0, RSTART + RLENGTH)
  }
}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, we can match all function calls, then use `match` a second time to find all string parameters:

```js
var input = `foo('Alice')
foo('Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie')
foo(flag ? 'Alice' : 'Bob')`;

var calls = Array.from(input.matchAll(/foo\((.*?)\)/g));
var arguments = calls.map(call => Array.from(call[1].matchAll(/'(.*?)'/g)));
for (var i=0; i < calls.length; ++i) {
    console.log(calls[i][0] + ": " + arguments[i].map(argument => argument[1]));
}
```

Comment: Thank you the approach works well! I just had to adapt it a bit to ensure that only `foo()` calls are matched and the single quotes are removed.